# Website lags badly in Chrome works fine in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I've gotten a site I've been working on fairly close to where I want it to be, and in Firefox it runs great. Chrome however, lags like no tomorrow when I scroll. I've tried disabling box-shadow, text-shadow, background repeating, custom fonts, etc. No luck.

Sorry my question isn't more specific, as I really can't figure out *why* its lagging.

(PS It doesn't work at all in IE, I'll be going back and doing the painful process of getting it to work there after I did all the design work.)

EDIT: Wow I could have sworn I put a link to the site, I absolutely meant to, really sorry!

http://zimmster.com/frostbyte/

Comment: Go into your inspector (F12) and click on the network tab. Refresh the page and see what is taking so long to load. You can then optimize.

Comment: It's not a loading time issue, but rather once the page is fully loaded, scrolling is really jumpy and not smooth in Chrome.

Comment: Have you tested on other machines?

Comment: Any function/plugin to take care of any events on scroll? Also maybe its related to hardware accel?

Comment: No there's pretty much no javascript going on at all. Definitely nothing related to scrolling

Comment: Static background? position:fixed? opacity? Facebook/etc plugins? Java,flash? Is it slow in Safari (also webkit-based) too? Can you show the site to us? For extra slowness, try zooming the page, THAT will be slow ! :)

Comment: Post a link to the site.

Comment: Can you list all the extensions you have installed for Chrome?

According to http://superuser.com/questions/333669/scrolling-in-chrome-on-windows-7-is-very-slow The last pass extension causes it too lag

Comment: It still lags in Incongnito Mode, which I believe disables all extensions.

Comment: Yes there is a static background image, with position: fixed. Not much opacity stuff going on, no social plugins (yet). No flash/java or any other plugins.

Comment: It's not js at all. I profiled it and the css is causing about 99% of the lag.

Comment: `@font-face` is notoriously slow. Try removing that and see if that improves performance.

Comment: That's what I meant by removing custom fonts. It doesn't affect the lag.

Comment: Looks fine in my chrome, pretty basic chrome latest version.

Answer (score 1):

Box shadow is a problem for Webkit browsers (its part of CSS3, which is still being implemented). This is strange because the issue seems to have been fixed [months ago](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=22102).

I removed the lines from post.css (it doesn't really affect the visuals) and it fixed the lag. (tested on Chrome 21)

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #202020;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px #202020;
```

Comment: I've removed those lines, I may have noticed a slight improvement, but it definitely isn't fixed. I'm using Chrome 19 (Latest Stable)

Comment: Strange. Try removing the post.css stylesheet and see if that speeds up the scrolling.

Comment: Removing it doesn't make it noticeably faster.

Comment: Thanks! You saved us some time.. strange lagging was caused by inner shadow of main site wrapper div =_=